# How to download zip file from server in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, server, zip

I am trying to download zip file from server and unzip the file to get its content in **Swift**. Does the normal way of NSURLSession work? Any advices for me? Thanks!

Comment: definitely use ZIPFoundation these days to handle zip files

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that the question is a little broad, so consider this as a short and generic answer.

**First:**

- You will need to download the archived file -you might want to use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1411511-downloadtask)-.
- After downloading the file, you should save it in a directory -let's say *documents*-.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/download-file-in-swift) to know how you can achive those steps.

**Second:**

After getting the archived file, you will unarchive it -I suggest to use a third-party library for doing this, such as [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)-.

**ALSO:**

You could use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-data-to-a-file) to handle the downloading proccess.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes. It was helpful. I can download the zip and trying to unzip it now. :D Thanks alot!

Comment: i actually tried to do it but i just a new member and i dont have enough reputation to do so. So sorry :(

Comment: It's ok :) you can vote up when having a 15+ score -which so  pretty easy to get-. For more information check the [Privileges - Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Cheers Up!

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: 2023 .. definitely ZIPFoundation is the current SPM for zip/unzip