# How to download zip file from server url and extract zip file save to local directory in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, zip, alamofire, gzip

I am trying to download zip file and extract zip file and save to local directory. When user come back and check unzipped file is available in local directory.

Here i am using alamofire for downloading zip file:

```
func zipFileApiCall() {
    let aString = fullFormKey
    let result = String((aString?.dropFirst(6))!)
    let s = String(result.dropLast(10))
    print("newFormKey", s )
    let vKey = self.convap(text: s)
    let newString = vKey.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "/", options: .literal, range: nil)
    print("full form key string /", newString )
    let v = "https://storage.url.com"+newString+"/assets.zip"
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
    AF.request(v).validate().responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("save form zip", response.value ?? "")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error:", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download zip file from server in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635799/how-to-download-zip-file-from-server-in-swift)

Comment: any other sample for downloading zip using alamofire

Comment: @ParameswaranV lots of examples and related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balamofire%5D+download+zip

Comment: now i can able download the zip file but unzip getting failed and how to get the all unzipped file @Scriptable

Comment: Show your updated code

Comment: unzipped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this repo to unzip your file : 
https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation

Comment: How to download zip file first?

Comment: While this repo *may* solve the question, it would be better as a comment. Please review [answer].