# Swift 3 file download not working

Tags: swift3

I got no experience in Objective-c, and new with Swift 3. I copied code from this link: [How to download file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/download-file-in-swift)

here the piece of code i copied in a playground session:

```
class Downloader {
    class func load(url: URL, to localUrl: URL, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .get)

        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Success: \(statusCode)")
                }

                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: localUrl)
                    completion()
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("error writing file \(localUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }

            } else {
                print("Failure: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Here the errors showed:

[playgroung errors picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbLEF.png)

Error now with the import Fondation line of code:

[error with the line of code import Fondation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoQc7.png)

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: Hello FelixSFD, how do you do it

Comment: Just write on the top of the file: `import Foundation`

Comment: Helloo Felix, that helped a lot, still one error, check the playground image uner this text. Tnk's for your help Felix.

Comment: The compiler tells you what's wrong: `.get` is not a valid enum case for `URLRequest.cachePolicy`.

Comment: Hello Eric, I got no idea what to put in there, I just copied this class from stack overview and I'm new to Swift, any idea what to use ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy This is a list of all cases you can put there