# Where to serve files to be downloaded by IOS

Tags: file, networking, download, server

In [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/download-file-in-swift), Devran Cosmo Uenal explained how to download a file with swift on an IOS device. Should the files that I want to download be stored on an FTP server? Or on a regular web server with Apache?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift or iOS. It applies to any client of your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLTask supports both protocols but the post you are referring to uses a regular http server.
Also the post uses the Alamofire library which I think only supports http