# How to perform an action in a website in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsurlsession

My question is how can i tell my application to for example go to this website search for a specefic link and download the content how should perform such thing in swift?

Comment: Rather than going to a website and searching for the link, if you know the link beforehand, consider simply downloading the file directly using a library like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: No i dont know the link thats it i want to get it from a page i want to have a some kind of link extractor for my app user searchs something and gets it link some kind of self buid api for a website that dosent provide the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) to parse the website for the link you are looking for, then download the file using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). If you want another way to download a file, here's a relevant Stack Overflow link: [How to download file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/how-to-download-file-in-swift)

Comment: Kanna can search website ? I had a downloader class but just want to extract links from websites

Comment: @namaama what you'll want to do is use the xml parser to look for the element you want

Comment: @namaama this link will help: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/08/web-scraping-and-parsing.html-in-swift-with-kanna-and-alamofire.html