# Can you get a song onto your iPhone thru your app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I would like to get songs from my computer to my iPhone inside of my own app.  This would be a music playing app that would have the ability to load songs into its own directory from some private source like a laptop or cloud storage.

Example: If I have 100 songs on a Google Drive and I write an iOS app that loads those files from the Google Drive into the apps directory.

iOS, iPhone, Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can download files into your app's Documents directory, which will be private to your app.

Here's a SO question on downloading a file in Swift/iOS that shows some concrete code examples: [How to download file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/how-to-download-file-in-swift)

You can also find many tutorials online on saving files and making HTTP requests in Swift.

You'll need to determine specifically how to make requests to your file provider e.g. Google Drive. This might involve not only the URL itself but also authentication, SSL validation etc. which are deeper topics in themselves but fully supported in Swift/iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely download songs to your phone from your computer. You just have to make a directory area in your app and have the song be fetched into that directory.