# Notify user application when transaction is completed

Tags: android, ios8

My application idea is about user and merchant loyalty card program application.

My idea:

User spend money at specific merchant , however in order for user to get the point, merchant would have to scan user's unique qr code to give point to user. regardless scanning successful or fail, it will notify user the transaction is completed. I do not want to notify through push notification but it directly displays on user phone [Successful / Failed] right after scanning. Is there any technology / service could achieve this ?

I could let user to scan merchant generated QR code to get point but due to user-friendliness of user side app we would like merchant to handle all the scanning regardless deduct or add point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service that will run on the background.

ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Tutorial: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/

Comment: Hi , what if user use iOS app but not android app how would they communicate ?

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667912/is-there-any-equivalent-of-services-of-android-in-ios